# how to reset function's static variable in c++

Tags: c++

when you try to use the following function for the first time it will give you correct answer which gives you the LCM of two numbers ( Least common multiple ).
for the second call with new parameters the static variable wont be starting at 1 which is going to give me wrong answer.
is there anyway to set it up to 1 before doing his recursive loop ?

```
int lcm(int a, int b)
{ 
    static int common = 1;

    if (common % a == 0 && common % b == 0)
        return common;

     common++;
     lcm(a, b);
     return common;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be static?

Comment: Make it non-static and pass it to `lcm` as a parameter. Even better, replace the recursion with a loop.

Comment: i'm working on big project, just put this simple example to deliver what my question is, and unfortunately, can't the static variable @drescherjm

Comment: If you want to touch it outside of the function, you have to make it global. If you don't want to accidentally change it, put it as `private` `static` into a class and `friend` functions as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in language mechanism for resetting function-level static variables. Although you can built your own way of communicating the need to reset the `static` to its initial value, it would remain a poorly-readable abuse of the language.

In particular, you should never use `static` variables in recursive functions, because non-reentrant recursive functions are nearly useless. In addition, your recursive implementation is painfully slow, because it tries candidate `lcm`s sequentially one by one. Feeding it two reasonably large prime numbers would result in stack overflow.

Rewrite your recursive `lcm` in a way that does not use `static`.

Comment: that's the answer i wanna hear, and stop flaming me for this example xD just put to deliver what i question is. Thank you so much <3

Comment: @NizarAlMshantaf You are welcome! I think I know where the example comes from. Unfortunately, the example is of very low quality. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142697/335858) is a much better implementation, which uses recursion to find `gcd`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use static variables for such a case. Use it as a parameter:

```
int lcm(int a, int b, int &common)
{ 
  if (common % a == 0 && common % b == 0)
    return common;

  common++;
  lcm(a, b, common);
  return common;
}

// now you can also overload it to avoid using argument:
int lcm(int a, int b)
{
    int common = 1;
    return lcm(a, b, common);
}
```

With static variable, you also break the thread-safety of the function. You would have to make sure only one thread is calling it.

***EDIT***

If you change the function a little bit:

```
int lcm(int a, int b, int common = 1)
{ 
   if (common % a == 0 && common % b == 0)
      return common;

   return lcm(a, b, ++common);
}
```

Now you don't need the common to be a reference and it's much simpler.